# How to get device info in flutter?

Tags: flutter

How to get deviceinfo without using [device_info_plus plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus).
Suggest me any other plugin or any other way.

This plugin shows conflicts when I import it in my projects.

Because device_info_plus >=7.0.0 depends on ffi ^2.0.1 and open_file 3.2.1 depends on ffi ^1.0.0, device_info_plus >=7.0.0 is incompatible with open_file 3.2.1.

Comment: See: https://github.com/crazecoder/open_file/issues/242 Basically, I would trust the developers of device_info_plus to maintain their package better than open_file, last version update was 22 months ago which suggests it is not worked on regularly.

Comment: yes. but my ques is different

Comment: Better to fix the conflict, device_info_plus is the best package for this. Up to you.